# SuperMicro compatible with ZC706 Xilinx Board

Tags: compatibility, xilinx, pci-e

We are looking to buy a SuperMicro machine to install the Xilinx ZC706 board on it for a specific project. We wanted to make sure which machine is and which intel processor family ( Haswell or Broadwell ) is compatible with the board?

We had a bad experience in PCIe card compatibilities with different machines, so we want to first investigate before placing the order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the Xilinx ZC706 is a board containing a PCI-e connector. 

If you plugin the card into whatever PC it would not be detected because you are missing curcial hardware building blocks. 

You need to create the PCI-e controller on the FPGA either by using an IP core from Xilinx or DIY. 

When you say that you had bad experience with pci-e compatibilities i would bet my money that it is your hardware design that is the culprit and not the motherboard.